# Python's += operator and lists

Tags: python

I though that `a += b` is just a shortcut for `a = a + b`. It seems it is not quite. Here's an example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b += [4, 5, 6]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a # is also changed
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But this works as expected:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b = b + [4, 5, 6]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a # not changed
[1, 2, 3]
```

Now, I understand that when I do `b = a`, `b` references the same list as `a` does, and if I do some operations on `b`, they automatically "apply" to `a` (since they both point to the same list, and that when I do `b = b + [4, 5, 6]` a new list is created and then assigned to `b`, but my question is...why this distinction? I mean, shouldn't `a += b` be a shorthand for `a = a + b`? This is what one would have expected...What's the logical explanation for this?

Comment: `+=` is not just a short-cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a+=b` is a shortcut for `a.extend(b)`, not `a=a+b` .. which, as you've said, creates a new list.

Comment: Probably would be good to point that this answer only applies when `a` is a `list`, not in general.

Comment: `+=` is not a shortcut; rather, its implementation happens to coincide with that of `extend`.

Comment: This is what I was asking actually. **Why** is this the intended behaviour for lists? Why it has been opted to work like this?

Comment: This is the "usual" expected behavior of those operators. `+=` modifies the object in place, `+` creates a new object that is the "sum" of both.

Comment: In the general case, `a += b` is a shortcut for `a.__iadd__(b)`, and `a + b` is a shortcut for `a.__add__(b)`. That is how the language works. The intention is to separate immutable operations and in-place mutations. `__add__` *should* be written so that the result is a new object which is the 'sum' of the original operands (whatever 'sum' means in terms of the class), while `__iadd__` *should* modify the left-hand side operand 'in-place' to take the sum as its value. Both have their uses; in-place modification may save space, while immutability may benefit (for instance) parallelization.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for! Thank you.